# codenmaeone - Location polling returning same location coordinates all the time

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the following code to poll the current location of the device
Location loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();

This is returning same location coordinates every time. Do I have to use getCurrentLocationSync()? Please advise where it could go wrong.

Also, should I use PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCUARCY or PRIORITY_MEDIUM_ACCUARCY instead of "PRIORITY_LOW_ACCUARCY"

Code:

```
public class TrackLocation implements LocationListener {

    private static TrackLocation instance = new TrackLocation();
    private Location lastLocation;
    private Timer time;

    public static TrackLocation getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void stopTracking() {
        if (time != null) {
            time.cancel();
        }
        time = null;
        LocationManager.getLocationManager().setLocationListener(null);
    }

    public void startTracking() {
        if (time != null) {
            stopTracking();
        }
        if (Preferences.get("LocationTracking", true)) {
            long delay = Server.instance.getLoctionPollingIntervalMillis();
            LocationManager.getLocationManager().setLocationListener(this,
                    new LocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_ACCUARCY, delay));
            time = new Timer();
            time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (lastLocation != null) {
                        Server.instance.updateLocationInServer(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude(), System.currentTimeMillis(), true);
                    }
                }
            }, 30000, delay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void providerStateChanged(int newState) {
    }
}
```

Comment: On which OS are you getting this? You don't need the sync method since the listener approach is better.

Comment: this is happening on both IOS and Android phones. Another question related to this is device will track the location even without internet connectivity/ no connectivity? It could be in the second location I don't have the proper wifi/carrier nework available.

Comment: Did you try setting this to high accuracy does it make a difference? 
Did you get a location permission prompt in iOS/Android? In iOS is the NS location build hint defined?